# Stumped by this line: (cos α + i sin α) + (cos β + i sin β)

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following example is from Abstract Algebra Theory and Applications
by Thomas W. Judson

Example 3. Recall that the circle group T consists of all complex numbers
z such that |z| = 1. We can define a homomorphism φ from the additive
group of real numbers R to T by φ : θ → cos θ + i sin θ. Indeed,
φ(α + β) = cos(α + β) + i sin(α + β)
= (cos α cos β − sin α sin β) + i(sin α cos β + cos α sin β)
= (cos α + i sin α) + (cos β + i sin β)                           [*]
= φ(α)φ(β).

I am unable to derive line [*] from the line above.
Could someone show me the way?

tnx...al

Comment: For that line, are you sure it had $(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha) + (\cos \beta + i \sin \beta)$ instead of $(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)(\cos \beta + i \sin \beta)$?

Comment: Nice catch Dennis.
The example is cut-and-paste from the book so the line
in question should be the product and not the sum.

Answer (score 3):

You have $\phi(\theta) = e^{i \theta}$.
Then $\phi(\alpha+\beta) = e^{i (\alpha + \beta)} = e^{i \alpha} e^{i  \beta} = \phi(\alpha) \phi(\beta)$.

Comment: exactly my line of thought :)

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the trigonometric identities for the sum of angles:
$$\phi(\alpha)\phi(\beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta -\sin\alpha \sin \beta +i(\cos \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \beta \sin \alpha)$$
$$=\cos(\alpha+\beta)+i\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\phi(\alpha+\beta)$$